# Single Responsible Principle and LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, single-responsibility-principle

I.e. my have the following model:

```
public class CompanyDto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CompanyLogo { get; set; }
    public string EmailUser { get; set; }
    public int UserCount { get; set; }
}
```

and some method in some repository class, which selects data from Db and push it to domain DTO class:

```
public List<CompanyDto> CompanyList()
{
    var list = (from i in _db.Companies
                select new CompanyDto()
                {
                    ID = i.Id,
                    CompanyLogo = i.CompanyLogo,
                    Name = i.Name,
                    UserCount = i.Users.Count,
                    EmailUser = i.UserDetail.Email
                }).ToList();

    return list;
}
```

as we can see, our BL model requires to get combine data from 3 entities (tables): Company, UserDetail and count of users from Users

It works and works fine. But I think about SRP. This principle says, that should be one and only one reason to change class. But in our case we have 2 reasons to change class:

1. change structure of DB entities
2. change DTO class

Does this code violate SRP?

Comment: There is another [SO question here](/questions/47871647/classes-with-crud-methods-violating-single-responsibility-principle) that might shed some ligjht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this code violate SRP ?

Yes-ish. But don't worry.

I believe your question might be better received at [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

IMO you are quite right but what I see is common and would go through all code reviews I am aware of.
I, presently, see no way of rewriting your code to 2 parts [both with their own SRP] as what you are describing is the *mapping* between two data carriers. (well, I see one by creating yet an in-betweeen class but that would be superfluous IMO)

What you *could do*; is to move the mapping [database entity `Company` -> DTO `CompanyDTO`] to another place. This place (here implemented as an extension method) is then responsible for all mappings from database entities to DTOs.

```
public static class CompanyExtensions{
    public static CompanyDto ToDto( this Company me ){
        return new CompanyDto{
            ID = me.Id, 
            ...the rest of the fields.
        }
    }
}
```

which will be called like so:

```
public List<CompanyDto> CompanyList()
{
    var result = (from company in _db.Companies
        select company.ToDto());
    return result.ToList();
}
```

The reason to use an extension method instead of a method in `CompanyDto` is that you don't want the database entities to leak out of your [DAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer).
The reason to use an extension method instead of a helper class is that you get intellisense.

Comment: If the method was `Expression<Func<Company, CompanyDto>> ToDto()` you could rewrite `CompanyList` to just `return _db.Companies.Select(ToDto).ToList()` for a more functional approach